# How to scale InfluxDB in docker service with persistent data

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, influxdb

### What have I done?

Got docker installed, version details below:

```
Server:
 Version:      17.11.0-ce
 API version:  1.34 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   1caf76c
 Built:        Mon Nov 20 18:36:09 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Docker running in swarm mode. Started a influxdb docker service by issuing following command.

```
# create network
docker network create influxdb-network --driver overlay
# create the service
docker service create --name 'influxdb' --network 'influxdb-network' --mount type=volume,source=influxdb-volume,destination=/var/lib/influxdb influxdb:1.4
```

Then, I created a dummy database in influxdb and inserted dummy data in it. Getting a count from influxdb is consistent as its a single service and single datasource (mounted volume). All good.

### Scale up

Scaled up the influxdb service to run 5 instances by using following command.

```
docker service scale influxdb=5
```

Now when I insert new data it get Load balanced and inserted to all the five instances separately. **How to have a consistent data across all 5 instances of influxdb?**

Answer (score 2):

Docker volumes are tightly coupled to the machine where they are created, thus they don't scale for a distributed application. This is still a lacking feature in docker ro have a distributed storage backend. You can workaround this
is issue by having a network storage such as NFS where the volume stores it data.

There are some projects that try to deal properly with this problem. Most notably [RexRay](https://rexray.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and tyhe discontinued project [Flocker](https://github.com/ClusterHQ/flocker).

In conclusion, when it comes to scaling databases, docker won't help much. You need to deal with scaling the database the way you would without having Docker.

Comment: Indeed. You have to use the scaling system of your database. Don't try to mount a volume from different containers, because you could corrupt your entire database.